# Why the change in torivors?

Tags: the-beyonders

When we first encounter torivors in the Beyonders, by Brandon Mull, they are alien entities of pure darkness. They communicate mentally in some fashion, but can't really be spoken with. Their primary danger is their incredible speed. They come with special swords that are among the only things capable of harming them.

By contrast, in the Outskirts series torivors are quite capable of communicating, are much more powerful, and like to manifest as good-looking people in revealing shirts. And, arguably most curious, no swords.

There's some line, by way of justification, of the torivors bound by wizards as being mere shadows, but I'm not interested in the plausibility of the in-universe reasoning.

Rather, *why* did Brandon decide to make this considerable change in the nature and presentation of torivors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that when the troubles came to lyrian  the wizards changed their nature so they must obey them  since five kingdoms takes place after beyonders it is possible that their form in five kingdoms is their original form and their Syrian form is designed to portray fear

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually more interested in the author's motivation, though.

Comment: Also, is Syrian a typo?